# Token list given to TikZ scope fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, token-lists

I want to construct a chain list on the fly and then use it in a `tikzpicture`, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\newtoks\stch

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \ForEach { O{1} m O{1} +m }
    { \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {#3} {#2} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\ForEach{4}{\edef\foo{\global\stch={\the\stch start chain=#1 going below,}}\foo}

\edef\grr{\the\stch}%% <<!!! expand token list into \grr>>
\StrGobbleRight{\grr}{1}[\grr]%% <<!!! remove last comma and put back into \grr>>

Bla bla bla: \grr

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [\grr]% This fails
    %[start chain=1 going below,start chain=2 going below,start chain=3 going below,start chain=4 going below]% this does not fail, even with spurious last comma
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}{% 
        \node[on chain=\x,xshift=\x*1in] {XX\x XX};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: test]

(The example graphic was generated with the explicit option.) The first option `[\grr]` to the `tikzpicture` fails with: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/start chain=1 going below,start chain=2 going below,start chain=3 going below,start chain=4 going below' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` A puzzle, as the text of the chain list seems to be constructed as expected.

Comment: `style/.expand once=\grr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix would be to use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[style/.expand once=\grr]
```

or

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[style/.expanded=\grr]
```

which is safe in this case because PGFKeys only “sees” `\grr` and not the `,` so it tries the whole thing as a key which explains your error message.

But you don't need `\foo` or `\grr` or `xstring` (an extra `,` won't hurt) or `\global` because the the L3 loop doesn't scope its content.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newtoks\stch
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \ForEach { O{1} m O{1} +m }
    { \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {#3} {#2} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ForEach{4}{\stch\expandafter{\the\stch start chain=#1 going below,}}
Bla bla bla: \the\stch

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[style/.expand once=\the\stch]
\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4}
  \node[on chain=\x, xshift=\x*1in] {XX\x XX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but you don't really need the toks and you can just use PGFFor for it by using the `.list` handler (which is an unscoped `\foreach` basically):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  stch/.style={start chain = #1 going below},
  stch/.list={1, ..., 4},
]
\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4}
  \node[on chain=\x, xshift=\x*1in] {XX\x XX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

And maybe you want to use one chain going right and *four* branches going below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  start chain=main going right,
  node distance=1em and 1cm,
]
\foreach \x/\y in {1/3, 2/5, 3/7, 4/2}
  \node[on chain] {branch \x}
   [start branch={\x} going below]
   node foreach \i in {1, ..., \y}
     [on chain] {\x: \i\ of \y};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm... In an earlier time you might have lain yourself open to accusations of being a sorcerer: Your final suggestion `start branch...` has spared the list from yet another query from me (yes, I had need of “your sorcerer’s ways”... ;>) ). Well done. And I've learned something (several somethings, actually).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but why don't you just use Ti*k*Z styles directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \ForEach { O{1} m O{1} +m }
    { \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {#3} {#2} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ForEach{4}{
    \tikzset{temp/.append style={start chain=#1 going below}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[temp]
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4} {% 
        \node[on chain=\x, xshift=\x*1in] {XX\x XX};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Qrrbrbirlbel's last answers are even more Ti*k*Zy =D

Comment: Nice. The more I use Ti*k*Z, the more I seem to have a **LOT** to learn. Of course, its 1200 page should have amply indicated that...